# Resizing image with SDL_gfx at specific size C++

Tags: c++, image, resize, sdl

I am using SDL_gfx trying to resize an image but i can't really get it done.

The case is that I have an :

```
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(0,0,32,SDL_FULLSCREEN);
```

and I also have a:

```
SDL_Surface* back_img = SDL_Load("back.jpg");
```

As you can see, I set the videomode to full screen, so the size of the screen surface will vary from pc to pc. I want to find a way to make back_img FIT on screen but i have two major problems.

1. `screen->w` and `screen->h` return a false value!
2. I can't resize the image to the specific size I want.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `screen->w` values return 0 because you set them to zero with `SDL_SetVideoMode(0,0,...`
Set them to some proper values like `SDL_SetVideoMode(800,600,32,SDL_FULLSCREEN);` you can change them later by calling the function again with different parametes.

Note; setting SDL fullscreen will automatically resize and stretch the image to fit the screen

Comment: So you suggest doing something like this :

SDL_BlitSurface(back_img, &rect , screen, NULL );
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 800 , 600 , 32 , SDL_FULLSCREEN );

and let SDL strech my image?

Comment: Something like that. Of course you can change the resolution to fit the desktop resolution when launching the game if your engine supports that.

Comment: but letting the SDL_SetVideoMode streching my background image won't be practical! I will have to re-call SDL_SetVideoMode everytime i want to stretch an image... doesn't make sence

Comment: You misunderstood, you set SDL_SetVideoMode once, i suggest you take a  look at a couple of SDL tutorials and try them out.

Comment: I do have a basic understanding of SDL (bliting images, rendering text, drawing rectangels...) it's just the first time that i get seriously involved with resolution and resizing.... :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use SDL_VideoInfo to get the current resolution. See the code below:

```
const SDL_VideoInfo *info = SDL_GetVideoInfo();
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( info->current_w, info->current_h, 32, SDL_FULLSCREEN );
```

Now your screen's resolution will match every PC's resolution.